# ubuntu 14.04 system program error detected

Tags: 14.04, login

just after login this error message comes and I have seen earlier solutions to this problem but in my case the desktop files are also not seen.nothing can be opened.neither the file explorer or system setting these are not even seen on scree.problems comes just after the startup.how can I fix this?

Comment: What error message? - askubuntu users aren't telepathic you know...

Comment: error msg is system program error detected.
asking to report error ? then two buttons cancel and report which do nothing when clicked

Answer (score 0):

I think you should log on using `TTY1` to clean up your crash directory by:

1. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to go to TTY1
2. log in there (1970s style)
3. Type: `sudo rm /var/crash/*`

Comment: i cant open terminal...it only shows the background..no desktop files nothing..no title bar and side bar nothing

Comment: @akb: As this was the only answer to your question, I've cleaned it up a bit.  If that wouldn't help, drop me a note @ Fabby and I'll have an in-depth look at your problem.

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+F1 is full-screen terminal, duh, @akb